# Merge overlapping paths

Tags: graph, gremlin, graph-databases

I have a query that returns a number of paths. Each path contains nodes with a type `t` property. The goal is to merge all 'overlapping' (nodes with the same type) sections of the paths, from the head until they diverge for the first time.

So my query currently returns paths like:

```
(t: 1)->(t: 2)->(t: 3)

(t: 1)->(t: 5)->(t: 3)

(t: 2)]->(t: 4)->(t: 3)->(t: 5)

(t: 2)->(t: 3)->(t: 3)->(t: 5)
```

would then result in:

```
    (2)->(3)
   /
(1)
   \
    (5)->(3)


    (4)->(3)->(5)
   /
(2)
   \
    (3)->(3)->(5)
```

I'm having difficulties finding examples that perform these kinds of queries. It would be great if someone could come up with an example or could point me to a good resource for learning these kinds of queries.

Comment: Does the `tree` step help?

Comment: I went ahead and added an example of `tree` in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tree` step can convert path history results into a more tree like structure. Using the [air-routes](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/tree/master/sample-data) data set:

```java
gremlin> g.V().where(out().count().is(3)).
           out().
           where(out().count().is(lt(4))).
           out().
           limit(5).
           path().
             by('code')

==>[TUP,GLH,TUP]
==>[TUP,GLH,DFW]
==>[GCC,RKS,SLC]
==>[GCC,RKS,DEN]
==>[GCC,RKS,GCC]
```

Using `tree`

```java
gremlin> g.V().where(out().count().is(3)).
           out().
           where(out().count().is(lt(4))).
           out().
           limit(5).
           tree().
             by('code')

==>[GCC:[RKS:[GCC:[],SLC:[],DEN:[]]],TUP:[GLH:[DFW:[],TUP:[]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty sure .tree() is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll quickly test it before accepting your solution.

Comment: Happy to help - I hope it gives you what you need.